# Simple PHP Question: Conditional CSS class based on user

Tags: php, css, wordpress, if-statement

I am using this code to show a different styling class for the comment box if the comment is made by the Admin

```
<li class="<?php if ($comment->user_id == 1) $oddcomment = "authorstyle"; echo $oddcomment; ?>"></li>
```

The admin has the user_id = 1. Now, what if i want to add user_id 5 and 6, how would I edit this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use the || operator (which means or):

```
if ($comment->user_id == 1 || $comment->user_id == 5 || $comment->user_id == 6)
```

Or you could use in_array:

```
if (in_array($comment->user_id, array(1, 5, 6))
```

Which looks nicer and is more maintainable. :)

Answer (score 2):

One (possibly) robust way to handle this kind of situation is to ask if the userid is one of a set of userids, thus something fairly trivial as a condition is:

```
in_array($comment->user_id, array(1,5,6))
```

Clearly you're developing some kind of permission system, so you'd really be better off coming up with a way to abstract user rights from their identities, and verifying a user has some privilege or status rather than in each place checking for said status.

One way to do this might be assigning a user to an admin group, and then checking against the group, rather than against all ids. Better still, you could consider setting some number of properties on the group, say, `has_style_xyz`, then check against `has_style_xyz` in your conditional.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
<li class="<?php
  if ($comment->user_id == 1)
     $oddcomment = "authorstyle";
  if ($comment->user_id == 2)
     $oddcomment = "somethingelse";
  if ($comment->user_id == 3)
     $oddcomment = "blahbalh";
 echo $oddcomment; ?>"></li>
```

... and so on, for multiple styles.

```
<li class="<?php
  if ($comment->user_id == 1 || $comment->user_id == 4 || $comment->user_id == 5)
     $oddcomment = "blahbalh";
 echo $oddcomment; ?>"></li>
```

... for multiple IDs with one style.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `OR` or `||` in your if statement.

`<li class="<?php if ($comment->user_id == 1 || $comment->user_id == 5 || $comment->user_id == 6) $oddcomment = "authorstyle"; echo $oddcomment; ?>"></li>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
<?php 
if ($comment->user_id == 1) 
   $oddcomment = "authorstyle"; 
else($comment->user_id == 5)
    $oddcomment = "authorstyle2"; 
else($comment->user_id == 6)
    $oddcomment = "authorstyle3"; 
?>

<li class="<?php echo $oddcomment; ?>"></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a simple way you could do something like this:

```
     <?php
        $liStyles[1] = 'authorstyle';
        $liStyles[5] = 'somestyle';
        $liStyles[6] = 'someotherstyle';
     ?>



 <li class="<?php echo $liStyles[$comment->user_id]; ?>"></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against using the user's ID to determine their admin status because then you will have to manually add/remove each user's ID.

This website is exactly what you want to do.

http://buildinternet.com/2009/09/automatically-highlight-admin-comments-in-wordpress/